# C++ std::map different key addressing the same index

Tags: c++, dictionary

Whilst doing refactoring I've somehow screwed up my code so the std::map I'm using stopped working properly.

I'm reassembling fragmented IPv4 packet.
Partially parsed `Packet` comes and if it's fragment of packet it becomes `Fragment` which has function for reassembling.

```
...    
if(packet.isIPv4() && packet.isFragment()){
    auto keyForMap = packet.key();
    auto it = fragments.find(keyForMap);
    auto fragmentNotFound = fragments.end();

    std::cout << "-----------------------"  << std::endl;        
    std::cout << "Fragments len: " << fragments.size() << std::endl;        

    keyForMap.print();

    if(it == fragmentNotFound){
        std::cout << "Not Found" << std::endl;
        fragments[keyForMap] = Fragment(packet);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;

        fragments[keyForMap].add(packet);
        /* reassembling function call and some processing */
        }
    }
}
...
```

Data types used:
`IPv4` is `std::array<uchar_t, 4>`

`fragments` is `fragments_t &`

`fragments_t` is `std::map<FragmentCommon, Fragment>`

```
struct FragmentCommon{
    FragmentCommon(IPv4 ipsrc,
                   IPv4 ipdst,
                   uchar_t protocol,
                   uint16_t identification) : ip_src(ipsrc),
                                              ip_dst(ipdst),
                                              protocol(protocol),
                                              identification(identification){};

    void print(){
        printf("key>%d.%d.%d.%d ", ip_src[0], ip_src[1], ip_src[2], ip_src[3]);
        printf("%d.%d.%d.%d ", ip_dst[0], ip_dst[1], ip_dst[2], ip_dst[3]);
        printf("%d %d\n", protocol, identification);
    };

    IPv4 ip_src;
    IPv4 ip_dst;
    uchar_t protocol;
    uint16_t identification;
};

static bool operator<(const struct FragmentCommon &lhs, const struct FragmentCommon &rhs){
    return lhs.ip_dst         < rhs.ip_dst &&
           lhs.ip_src         < rhs.ip_src &&
           lhs.protocol       < rhs.protocol &&
           lhs.identification < rhs.identification;
}
```

This is output my code gives me:

```
-----------------------
Fragments len: 0 // Correct (this is first fragment so nothing is in map)
key>192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4 6 1
Not Found // So it's added into map
-----------------------
Fragments len: 1 // Correct (1st fragment is in map)
key>192.168.1.5 192.168.1.6 6 1
Found // Not correct...keys are different
-----------------------
Fragments len: 1
key>192.168.1.5 192.168.1.6 6 1
Found
-----------------------
Fragments len: 1
key>192.168.1.5 192.168.1.6 6 1
Found
-----------------------
```

Comment: Does `FragmentCommon` have operator `<`? I'm not sure how it would ever work without, but it's not shown and your map doesn't have a custom comparator.

Comment: @Useless Yes it has
`static bool operator<(const struct FragmentCommon &lhs, const struct FragmentCommon &rhs){
    return lhs.ip_dst < rhs.ip_dst;
}`

Comment: Please edit your question to add that critical information. So given that definition, what does `operator<` for `IPv4` do?

Comment: That should have been included in the question, since it's part of the public interface of the type. The function is actually wrong in general (it should compare _all_ members), but ought to work in your example. However, since you don't show your actual code: is that operator visible when the map is declared? Is it in the same namespace as `FragmentCommon` and definitely being used? When you test it in isolation, does it do what you expect?

Comment: @SamoPoláček -- You posted irrelevant functions such as `print()`, but you left out `operator <` in your question, which is the major part of `std::map` and how it works.

Comment: The reason why I did't include `operator<` is that my code worked before and then stopped working after some refactoring that did't include change of `operator<`. `operator<` is included in question now.

Comment: @Useless Yes, my `operator<` is being used.

Comment: @SamoPoláček -- What is `IPv4`?  And how is `operator <` defined for that type?  Also, if you're talking about refactoring, your code snippet for inserting into the map can be shortened to half of what it is now by using `map::insert()` instead of `std::map::operator [ ]`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie IPv4 is `typedef uchar_t IPv4[4];` and that's probably the reason my code stopped working. Before refactoring IPv4 was uint32_t.  So my `operator<` now compares pointers to uchar_t but not values inside.

Comment: @SamoPoláček - The probable fix is to define the `IPv4::operator <` using `std::tie` for the 4 components.

Comment: @SamoPoláček -- Also, I suggest changing to `typedef std::array<uchar_t,4> IPv4;` and then your code should work as-is, since `std::array` has a built-in `operator <` that does what you probably wanted to do.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok...I had to change the code a little bit more to get successfull compile without warnings ...now the question is completely changed so please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @SamoPoláček -- Use `std::tie` in your `operator <`.  If this works, I will post it as an answer: `return std::tie(lhs.ip_dst,  lhs.ip_src lhs.protocol, lhs.identification) < std::tie(rhs.ip_dst, rhs.ip_src. rhs.protocol ,rhs.identification);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, code works now. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @PaulMCKenzie I will also take a look at suggested map::insert()

Comment: @SamoPoláček -- I posted an answer.  As to using `map::insert()`, the trick is the return value when calling `insert()`.  The return value tells you exactly the results of the `insert` call, which you then use later.  By using the return value correctly, you need just a single call to `insert`, and an *unconditional* (no `if` needed) `add()` function (if you start off with an empty `Fragment` on construction of a new insertion into the map).

Comment: @SamoPoláček [See this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1582f52aefdb1da).  No need to do a `find` and an `if`.  Just `insert()` and use the return value accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you've posted and stated in the question, since `IPv4` is a `std::array<uchar_t,4>` (I'm assuming that `uchar_t` is an alias for `unsigned char`), you can define `operator <` for `FragmentCommon` using [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

Using `std::tie` is simpler and less-error prone for defining a *strict-weak ordering* (required for `std::map` keys) when dealing with multiple values to test for in a "cascading" fashion.

```
#include <tuple>
//...
static bool operator < (const struct FragmentCommon &lhs, const struct FragmentCommon &rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.ip_dst, lhs.ip_src, lhs.protocol, lhs.identification) < 
           std::tie(rhs.ip_dst, rhs.ip_src, rhs.protocol, rhs.identification);
}
```

Since [std::array has operator <](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) defined, using `std::tie` works correctly when using all 4 arguments in each `std::tie`.